# Omission de mots dans le second élément des coordinations de deux groupes nominaux

Tags: coordination, ellipse

« dans la colonne verte et dans la colonne rouge » est correct; sur quatre  possibilités d'omission la signification ne change pas pour deux d'entre elles et la quatrième est incorrecte. Est-ce que la troisième possibilité résulte en une expression correcte avec la même signification?

1. **correct** - dans la colonne verte et dans la rouge
2. **correct** - dans la colonne verte et  la colonne rouge
3. **pas sûr** - dans la colonne verte et  la  rouge
4. **incorrect** - dans la colonne verte et rouge

Comment: 4. dans les colonnes verte et rouge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La troisième sera certainement comprise avec le sens attendu. Ce style d'ellipse est courant en français parlé.

La quatrième peut être corrigée en :

> dans les colonnes verte et rouge.

mais devient alors plus imprécise et ambiguë.